# While loop inside for-each - for-each variable scope in Java

Tags: java, foreach, while-loop

Is it possible to have a While loop inside a For-each loop and use the For-each iterator variable inside the While loop?

I have this code for example:

```
    String[] num = {"1", "2", "3", "3", "5"};
    ArrayList<String> missingNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String strTemp : num) {
        while (!Arrays.asList(num).contains(strTemp)) {
            missingNumbers.add(strTemp);
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(missingNumbers.toString().join(",", missingNumbers));
```

I want the while loop to check if the iterator **for-each variable** strTemp (representing the Array num) is **NOT present** in the Array num. If this is the case -> **add it** to the list.

However, the variable is not added to the list - it`s empty when I print it.

I tested changing the for/each loop with a normal for loop and I got the expected result of 4.

Is it something related to the for/each variable scope? Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But everything in num is already in num. And that's what you are checking.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your `for-each` loop is over the values (as `String`(s)) "1, 2, 3, 3, 5" (in that order). There is **never** a case where that set of values does not contain a value from that particular set.

Comment: My mistake, I just updated the original post - I want to check if the for-each variable is NOT presented in the Array num. Does it make more sense now? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you want to add to `missingNumbers` every value from `num` which is not already present in `missingNumbers`? Is that your case?

Comment: No, it doesn't make more sense. The foreach variable is always a value of num, since the foreach loop is `for (String strTemp : num)`. This means: "for every element of num". So checking if it's not present is num is useless. As useless as checking if every person in a room is absent from the room.

Comment: Hi Pavel, yes, this is exactly my case! Can that be done with a While loop within a For/Each loop?

Comment: You're iterating over `num`, and then checking if each value is in num (or not). There's no real point in doing that because every value in num is guaranteed to be in num.

Comment: Thanks a lot JB Nizet and Zach! I got it :-) This is impossible to be done with a for/each loop, as the iterator variable of the for/each is ALWAYS an item of the array it is iterating.
This explains why my code works with standard for loop, where i = 1, and then iterates until num.length and checks if each "i" is present in num or not (and if not --> add it to missingNumbers).